# Do I need to buy Cataclysm to unlock the new race/class combinations in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Do I need to own Cataclysm to make a character using one of [the new race/class combinations](http://www.worldofwarcraft.com/cataclysm/_images/features/raceclassmatrix_en_US.jpg) like troll druids or dwarf mages?

If not, are these combinations available now, or do I need to wait until Cataclysm actually launches on Dec. 7th?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like the content within the most recent 4.0.3 patch (i.e., the shattering), all the changes and new quests, etc. are available to anyone with the base game.

According to the official patch notes: http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/1214741

The new race / class combinations are already available in the game. (See the 2nd bulletpoint, reprinted below):

> New Race/Class Combinations In the
>   wake of a world on the brink of
>   destruction, members of the Horde and
>   Alliance have taken to new cultures
>   and studies, mastering crafts
>   previously foreign to them. Many
>   existing playable races now have new
>   class combinations. Check the official
>   World of Warcraft: Cataclysm website
>   for a breakdown of the new
>   combinations.

Comment: Just not the combos on the new races

Comment: Just not the new races. Period.

Comment: what @Raven Dreamer, @Keith said... +1 guys..